# how can i extract dates by using grep? I need to match " , ", " / ", " . ", " - " for each one

Tags: r, regex

### targets: "2019,3,1", "2019,03,01", "2019.03.01", "2019-03-01", " '21/3/1"

```
year<-c("2019,3,1", "2019,03,01", "2019.03.01", "2019-03-01", " '21/3/1", "2019,3-1", "2019-03=01", "2019,03.01", "2019/03-01", "2019-350-01")

grep("",year,value=T)
```

I tried

```
grep("[20 ']19([,./-]0?[3])[,./-](0?[1])$",year,value=T)
```

but I still have "2019,3-1" "2019,03.01" "2019/03-01"

Comment: Some of these dates look bogus to me, e.g. the last one `2019-350-01`.  Is your requirement only to _extract_ dates, or do you also have the need to do some _validation_ here?

Comment: I only need to extract the correct ones. As I mentioned as targets: "2019,3,1", "2019,03,01", "2019.03.01", "2019-03-01", " '21/3/1", i need these 5.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
year<-c("2019,3,1", "2019,03,01", "2019.03.01", "2019-03-01", " '21/3/1", "2019,3-1", "2019-03=01", "2019,03.01", "2019/03-01", "2019-350-01")

grep("\\d{2,4}([,./-])\\d{1,2}\\1{1}\\d{1,2}",year,value=T)
```

**Detail**:

- `\\d{2,4}`: a digit has length range from 2 to 4 respectively year
- `([,./-])`: group character (default group 1).
- `\\d{1,2}`: a digit has length range 1 or 2 respectively month
- `\\1{1}`:  same value as captured in Group 1 and has length 1
- `\\d{1,2}`: a digit has length range 1 or 2 respectively day

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kKwT.png)

I usually use [regex101](https://regex101.com/) for visualization but it doesn't have for R. There is a small modify to convert from python regex to R regex. For example in python using \d, in R using \\d.

Hope this useful.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct.

Comment: @AdityaDees ok I have added information.

Answer (score 1):

As others noted, it depends how strict you want to be about what you consider a date, but if you wish to view any symbol between numbers as demarcating between year/month/day and use regex

```
as.Date(gsub("[^0-9]", "/", year),format = "%Y/%m/%d"))
```

It converts anything but number to /, thus, gives NA for the one that leads with ' and the one with month 350

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really need a regular expression solution, you could use the `ymd()` function from the `lubridate` package.

```
library(lubridate)
ymd(year)
```

Its output:

```
 [1] "2019-03-01" "2019-03-01" "2019-03-01" "2019-03-01" "2021-03-01"
 [6] "2019-03-01" "2019-03-01" "2019-03-01" "2019-03-01" NA          
Warning message:
 1 failed to parse.
```

The one that failed to parse is `"2019-350-01"`, which clearly can't be directly interpreted as a date.